# What is the alternative of Navigator.permissions for Safari Browser?

Tags: reactjs, safari, cross-browser

I'm using the below code and it works fine for Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't work on Safari. In React js. What is the alternative for it in Safari browser?

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {

 if (result.state == 'granted') {
   cb(true)
 }else if(result.state == 'prompt'){
   cb(false)
 }

});
```

Comment: Did you find a work around?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. I also tried to do this exact code but Safari (nor Safari for iOS) support the [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API).

However, I was able to do a workaround by using the [Navigator API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).

Try using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)`; if it triggers the success callback, the user has granted access to its location.